# Cache <cfstoredproc> results

Tags: caching, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfstoredproc

Is there any way to cache the results of a `<cfstoredproc>` tag? The `<cfquery>` tag makes it easy with the `cachedwithin` attribute but there doesn't seem to be anything for `<cfstoredproc>`.

Am I missing something simple or is this functionality just missing from ColdFusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there, just Adobe glossary missed it. Check the comments at the end of the tag entry:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_r-s_22.html

Also documentation reference here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/appFramework_20.html

Comment: Note my response is specifically addressing the Coldfusion-8 tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly documented in the CF9 docs. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d55.html